# Using the Array Template Parameter for a Return

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, reference, size

(I can't seem to find a name for this paradigm, but you'll get a bonus upvote if you can!) This template paradigm is used to prevent an array from decaying into a pointer:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(const char (&bar) [N]);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/jDLdB7)

We are able to use `N` in the body of `foo` to get the size off `bar`. Given `const char array[] = "lorem ipsum"` we use this call `foo(array)` to define `bar` as a `const char (&) [12]`, effectively passing 2 parameters for the price of one.

---

I want to use this same idea but in a return, for example:

```
template <size_t N>
const char (&) [N] foo(const char (&bar) [N]);
```

Such that I could pass the array through, and have another reference to it, such as: `auto result = foo(bar)`

The code I have here yields the error:

> unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

For clarification, I want to be able to have a function return that will result in the equivalent of:

```
auto& result = bar;
```

Such that `result` will be a `const char (&) [*]` where `*` is the size of `bar`.

Comment: It's called "passing by reference" :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmmm... I was hoping for something a bit more exotic, but I suppose it is :J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ syntax is wonderful:

```
template <std::size_t N>
const char (&f(const char (&arr)[N]))[N]    // take that, Lisp
{
    return arr;
}
```

For the less masochistic:

```
template <std::size_t N> using CarrN = const char[N];

template <std::size_t N>
CarrN<N> & f(CarrN<N> & arr)
{
    return arr;
}
```

As for terminology: We usually say that "`arr` is *passed by reference*", though the more discerning user might say "passed as an lvalue" (and also returned as such).

Comment: Errr... sorry about that, when I fix that it shows what I'm talking about. `test` is a `const char*&` not a `const char (&) [12]`. It's size outputs as 4.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Say `auto&& test = ...`. You cannot pass arrays as prvalues or initialize from arrays (string literals are an exception). [Demo](http://ideone.com/99K5eL). (And yes, I saw that goalpost move :-).)

Comment: So... we can't return a reference? An rvalue means that I cannot effect the original... depending upon the implementation :( (I'm not sure what you mean by moving the goalposts, this is the point of the question, get a reference, to the un-decayed array?)

Comment: @JonathanMee: You *can* return a reference, as the code capturing it with `auto&&` shows. But you can't initialize an array from another array. E.g. you can't say `int a[] = f();`.

Comment: I thought the point of your question was the syntax of a function declaration. Now we're on to semantics of array types...

Comment: I've clarified my question. Is there no way to return the type `const char (&) [12]` and *not* have it decay on assignment to a variable?

Comment: @JonathanMee: I thought I showed just that: Bind the return value to a reference. Then there's no decay.

Comment: Thanks for straitening me out. I thought [you'd said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842058/using-the-array-template-parameter-for-a-return/36842111?noredirect=1#comment61256048_36842111) that I needed to assign the return of `f` to an `auto&&` variable. I got confused there. After your comment I tested and you can in fact assign this to an `auto&` variable which is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Yes, `auto&&` is a lazy way to say "I want a reference". You can also spell the actual type out if you prefer.

Comment: Are you saying that `auto&&` will decay to a regular reference?

Comment: @JonathanMee: It doesn't "decay", but it performs template argument deduction in a fashion too complex to explain in a comment (search for "reference collapsing") and results in an lvalue reference type.